# php mysql check if vendor has 3 low consecutive ratings

Tags: php, mysql, apache, vendor

on my ratings table for my software i have 4 fields.
id autoincrement
rvid  vendor id
ratedate  date of rating
rating  the actual numeric rating

I have done alot with it over the last few months but this time im stumped and i cant get a clear picture in my head of the best way to do this.  What i am trying to do is find out if the vendor has had 3 low 'consecutive' ratings.  If their last three ratings have been < 3 then i want to flag them.

I have been playing with this for a few hours now so i thought i would ask (not for the answer) but for some path direction just to push me forward, im stuck in thought going in circles here.

I have tried GROUP BY and several ORDER BY but those attempts did not go well and so i am wondering if this is not a mysql answer but a php answer.  In other words maybe i just need to take what i have so far and just move to the php side of things via usort and the like and do it that way.

Here is what i have so far i did select id as well at first thinking that was the best way to get the last consective but then i had a small breakthrough that if they have had 3 in a row the id does not matter, so i took it out of the query.

```
  $sql = "SELECT `rvid`, `rating` FROM `vendor_ratings_archive` WHERE `rating` <= '3' ORDER BY `rvid` DESC";
```

which give me this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 7
        [rating] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 5
        [rating] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 5
        [rating] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 5
        [rating] => 3
    )

)
```

this is just just samples i tossed in the fields, and there are only 4 rows here where as in live it will be tons of rows. But basically this tells me that these are the vendors that have low ratings in the table.  And that is where i get stumpted.   I can only do one sort in the query so that is why i am thinking that i need to take this and move to the php side to finish it off.

I think i need to sort the elements by rvid with php first i think, and then see if three elements in a row are the same vender (rvid).

Hope that makes sense.  My brain hurts lol...

update - here is all of the table data using *

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [rvid] => 7
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [rvid] => 5
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [rvid] => 5
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [rvid] => 5
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 3
    )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can begin approaching this - completely in SQL:

- Get the last rating for the vendor. ORDER BY date DESC, limit 1.
- Get the second to last rating for the vendor. ORDER BY date DESC, limit 1, OFFSET 1.

Then write a query that does a LEFT join of the first two tables. You will have a dataset that has three columns:

- vendor id
- last rating
- second to last rating

Then you can write an expression that says "if column1 is <3 and column2 < 3, then this new column is true"

You should be able to extend this to three columns relatively easily.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i feel like i have coders block and im just sitting here staring at the screen in a haze lol..   That does help thanks... :)

Comment: Get up from your desk and don't look at a monitor for at least 10 minutes. Get a cup of coffee, stretch, don't do anything code-related. Then clarity will come.

Comment: actually i went to the outhouse and the answer came to me lol - its true omg :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what a came up with to solve this riddle.   I think explaining it on here helped as well as Alex also helped as he keyed my brain on using the date. I first started looking at using if statment inside of the query and actually that got my brain out of the box and then it hit me what to do.

It is not perfect and certainly could use some trimming to reduce the code, but i understand it and it seems to work, so that is par for me on this course.

the query...

```
 $sql = "SELECT `rvid`, `ratedate`,`rating` FROM `vendor_ratings_archive` WHERE `rating` <= '3' ORDER BY `ratedate`, `rvid`  DESC";
```

which gives me this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 7
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 5
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 5
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [rvid] => 5
        [ratedate] => 2016-05-01
        [rating] => 3
    )

 )
```

**notice how vendor (rvid) 5 is grouped together which is an added plus.**

next a simple foreach to load a new array

```
     foreach($results as $yield)
     {  

      $rvidarray[] = $yield['rvid'];          

      }//close foreach
```

which gives me this

Array
   (
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 5
   )

then we count the array values to group dups

```
 $rvidcounter = array_count_values($rvidarray);
```

which results in this

```
Array(
[7] => 1
[5] => 3
)
```

so now vender 7 as 1 low score and vendor 5 has 3 low scores and since they were already sorted by date i know that its consecutive. Well it sounds good anyway lol ")

then we create our final array with another foreach

```
     foreach($rvidcounter as $key => $value)
     {    
        //anything 3 or over is your watchlist

        if($value > 2)
        {
          $watchlist[] = $key; //rvid number stored
         }      

         }//close foreach
```

which gives me this

```
Array
(
[0] => 5
)
```

this was all done in a service function. So the final deal is everyone in this array has over 3 consecutive low ratings and then i just use a returned array back in my normal php process file and grab the name of each vender by id and pass that to the html and print out the list.

done...

please feel free to improve on this if you like. I may or may not use it because the above code makes sense to me. Something more complicated may not make sense to me 6 mos from now lol   But it would be interesting to see what someone comes up with to shorten the process a bit.

Thanks so much and Happy Coding !!!!!
Dave :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in SQL like that:

```
SET @rvid = -1;

SELECT DISTINCT rvid FROM
(
  SELECT
    rvid,

    @neg := rating<3,  /* 0 or 1 for addition in next line */
    @count := IF(@rvid <> rvid , @neg, @count+@neg) AS `count`, /* set or add */
    @rvid := rvid      /* remember last row */
  FROM
    testdb.venrate

  ORDER BY
    rvid, datetime desc

) subq

WHERE   count>=3
;
```

You set a variable to a non existing id. In each chronologically sorted row you check if rating is too low, that results in 1 (too low) or 0 (ok). If rvid is not equal to the last rvid, it means a new vender section is beginning. On begin of section set the value 0 or 1, else add this value. Finally store the current row's rvid for comparison in next row process.

The code above is looking for **3 consecutive low ratings** (low means a value **less than 3**) over all the time.

A small modification checks if all the **latest 3 ratings** has been **equal to or less than 3**:

```
SET @rvid = -1;

SELECT DISTINCT
  rvid
FROM
(
  SELECT
    rvid,

    @high_found := rating>3 OR (@rvid = rvid AND @high_found) unflag,
    @count := IF(@rvid <> rvid , 1, @count+1) AS `count`,
    @rvid := rvid      /* remember last row */

  FROM
    testdb.venrate

  ORDER BY
    rvid, datetime desc

) subq

WHERE count=3 AND NOT unflag
;
```

Comment: wow!  impressive bit of coding there Q...  way over my head but very cool and so simple lol  :)

Comment: I've added a short explanation.

Comment: Well after further testing it appears that it tags them with 3 or more bad ratings but its not consecutive.  I tested with ratings of 1 1 6 4 3  which is not consecutive 3 or under and it still tagged. I want them to come off the list as soon as they get a good rating.  Maybe i should add a consecutive field to the table.  Then when i update the table i could check the last rating value and then increment the value in the new field. Once they have a good review then it resets the counter for the field.  Then i can just check how many consecutive using the consecutive field.  Sounds Logical.

Comment: Since you asked for a query that checks for consecutive low rates, of course it will tag a vendor getting a rating of 1 3 **2 2 1** 4 1, but not: 1 3 2 1 3 4 1. Count grows with every low rating and is reset on a high rating. Then the result is filtered by count >=3.

Comment: Yes :) so what should happen is starting with highest record left to right.  132621 should be tagged because 132 are the last three records and they are all 3 and under ratings.  However if it was 136621 then that is not tagged because the ratings 1 and 3 are in the catch box but 6 is out.  Now if they get another bad rating lets say 1136621 then yes.  But as long as the low ratings are not 3 in a row then no tag.

Comment: Yes, exactly that is done, but with a rating value of 3 consired as ok. ("If their last three ratings have been < 3 then i want to flag them.") On other place you are speaking of just three consecutive ratings. What exactly do you intend to do now? Raise `WHERE count>=3` to any lowest value cosidered to be a high rating.

Comment: OK, but regarding my original query for my answer, i think the downfall with that is i pull only <= 3, i need to pull all ratings in the first query so that i can filter for consecutive exceptions.  Right now that posted query of mine is just pulling ALL <= 3 and does not filter for breaks in the pattern. If that makes sense.

Comment: I've understood and my query is doing what that - looking for breaks. So, are you actually looking for **three consecutive** low ratings or only if the **last three** are low? And what value is considered as the minimum high rating?

Comment: 3 or below are bad.  The enum field for ratings is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6  with 3 being poor and 4 being fair.  So i want to pull poor and below so 3 and below.   Regarding the 3, it has to be the last three.  The feeling is just because they have 3 in life does not mean they are bad.  Maybe they improved.  So it has to be the last three ratings.  :)

Comment: Understand what i am trying to do is not just use your code but also fix mine that i posted so that i dont offer a solution with my post that does not work.  So i am doing both codes :)  And to make sure they both work :)

Comment: I've added a little modification.

Comment: Thanks ;)  now i will work on mine :)  for mine i have pulled all ratings and then i will check each result for bad rating, if bad i will store in another array, then when i get the next result i will check the array if the id already exits and how many, if its 3x then the id gets passed to a final array, if not and the next result is higher, then i remove the key id from the temp array.   I think this will work, i will post my changes to my code when i have it working as well.  Thanks so much everyone :)  ps. since it is sorted by date already then that helps.